# CONVERTING MULTIVALUE TABLES IN UNIDATA

Tags: unidata

I Have a multivalued table which needs to be unnested in unidata. I'm using CONVERT.SQL to convert my table to sql first.

SYNTAX I'm using is CONVERT.SQL  .I get the following error.
field 'CHECK.NUM': association and phrase 'CHECK' mismatch
serious problems prevented automatic conversion

0 files have been converted

Comment: There are to places that define the association for MultiValue attributes defined in the dictionary.  The first is in the field/attribute definition itself, and the other is the Phrase that describes all fields defined in the association.  What do the CHECK and CHECK.NUM dictionary items look like?

Comment: CHECK           PH  CHECK.NUM TRN
                    .DATE CHECK.A
                    MT CASH.AMT M
                    ISC.AMT CASH.
                    BATCH.NUM

CHECK.NUM       D              13      Check Number    12L    M  CHECK_NUM_
                                                                 ASSOC